# get the parent nodes to a given node in d3 dendogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a beginner in javascript/flask and I am trying to experiment with this d3 dendogram example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570

What I am trying to get is, when a node is clicked, return the parent nodes to the flask app server.

For example: If i click on `display` node, then server gets "`flare,display`"

if `cluster` node is clicked, then server gets "`flare,analytics,cluster`"

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, for this example, and others created with the same method, the datum property `id` holds the parent node names, `display` has an id of `flare.display`. So you just need to replace the periods with commas and use an on click event to get the relevant id and trigger whatever you need: https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/raw/4358ca9989902fae71cf91b38dc4de56/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple to get the parents of the clicked node. Just use [`ancestors()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_ancestors), which:

> Returns the array of ancestors nodes, starting with this node, then followed by each parent up to the root.

So, in your case...

```
node.on("click", function(d){
    console.log(d.ancestors())
});
```

.. will show all the ancestors in the console, as an array.

Here is the forked bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/e36d4af364642a70818987941aa192c8/c75e620e662a6899d8df34c287fc5ea00d049513

In that code I'm mapping the array to get the `id` property of each node.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.. noob question.. but how/where do i specify the url where the server can capture this request?

Comment: Well, you had two very distinct questions here (which is a reason to close at SO). So, now that you have the answer for the first one, post *another* question regarding this other issue, with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847130/how-to-send-the-click-data-from-d3-to-flask-server

Answer (score 1):

You can recurse over the clicked data:

```
var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      //attach a click listener to the group
      .on("click", function(d){
        var children = [];
        //recursively call parent
        var recurse = function(c){
          //recurse unless no parent is found
          if (c.parent){
            children.push(c.parent.id);
            recurse(c.parent)
          }
        }
        recurse(d)//call recurse on clicked node
        console.log(children)
        //send children to server via AJAX
      })
```

working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3kSqSKkBWk1CAXoIeIue?p=preview)